# CSS Link Static Page

Tags: html, css, django, wagtail

Before you mark this as a duplicate, I have indeed already looked at the django forums, tutorials, etc.

I have a blog I made with Django, the blog's index page template needs to have a css stylesheet that I have linked in my static folder. (Folder Tree attached
[attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jwT4.png)).

In the html for the template I have the following code:

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'blog/style.css' %}" />
```

Why is this not working! Thanks!

EDIT: I found this in my sitename/base.py file:

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static'),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Could it be a problem with the directories? `manage.py collectstatic -l` says:

> 196 static files symlinked to
>   '/home/myusername/webapps/mysite/static'.

Comment: Add a `/` before blog: `href="{% static '/blog/style.css' %}"`

Comment: I feel its unable to reach the style.css file. I think '../blog/style.css'  should work

Comment: @KobyDouek No luck :(

Comment: @ChetanV Nothing. Django automatically looks for static files in a folder named static so you don't have to do the ../

Comment: Did you add static path to root urlpatterns: `urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)`?

Comment: KobyDouek and ChetanV thanks for the help :)

Comment: @neverwalkaloner in base.py? Posted changes. Found Static files in base.py

Comment: In urls.py file. Check this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development If this will not help try to remove `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'` from base.py

Comment: What version of Django are you using?

Comment: @neverwalkaloner Nothing happened. Still not working.

Comment: @Lonoshea I am using Wagtail with Django Version 1.11.4 and Wagtail version 1.12

Comment: @neverwalkaloner I couldn't remove the STATIC_ROOT = os.path... lines because it gives an error: `You're using the staticfiles app without having set the required STATIC_URL setting.`

Comment: From the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#static), have you tried referencing just `style` without the `blog/` and `.css`?

Comment: @Lonoshea No Luck. Same issue.

Comment: I am not familiar with Wagtail, but you may want to try `{% load staticfiles %}` instead of `{% load static %}`

Comment: @Lonoshea Thanks for the help, but still no luck :(

Comment: This is not as fancy but can you call the .css file like this `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/blog/style.css' %}" media="all"/>`

Comment: @Lonoshea that didn't work either

Comment: @CarterF I forgot to ask, are you doing this locally or on a live server? Do you have a `STATICFILES_STORAGE` variable? If so, what is it? If you are testing locally - try adding this `STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'` -- this should help make the static templatetag function locally

Comment: @Lonoshea I am running this locally, but I can migrate it over to a live server if that would be easier?

Answer (score 0):

Check the console while opening the view accessing this CSS file. The cmd console will print the absolute URL they will use to find CSS file. From the url, you can identify what is the problem. See how the URL is built.

Comment: `[25/Aug/2017 20:03:11] "GET /blog/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3090
[25/Aug/2017 20:03:12] "GET /blog/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3090`

Comment: try without the below parts in settings.py

`STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static'),
]`

Comment: or atleast this -
 `STATICFILES_DIRS = [ os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static'), ]`

I think it is looking for static folder in root directory because of this.

Answer (score 0):

comment the `STATICFILES_URL [..], STATICFILE_FINDERS [..]` and add the staticfiles_url like this:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

Comment: I forget, change your load static to load staticfiles